# R: Isotonic regression Minimisation

Tags: r, regression, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, minimization

I want minimize the following equation:

```
F=SUM{u 1:20}sum{w 1:10}   Quw(ruw-yuw)
```

with the following constraints:

```
yuw >= yu,w+1
yuw >= yu-1,w
y20,0 >= 100
y0,10 >= 0
```

I have a 20*10 ruw and 20*10 quw matrix, I now need to generate a yuw matrix which adheres to the constraints. I am coding in R and am familiar with the lpsolve and optimx packages, but don't know how to use them for this particular question.

Comment: In my solution, I show that the optimal solution doesn't depend on the `ruw` values. Are you missing something in your formulation, e.g. an absolute value in the objective?

Comment: I  stated the final two constraints incorrectly, the final two constraints should actually be y20,0 = 100 and y0,10 = 0.

Comment: Josilber, the (ruw-yuw) should be squared like: F=SUM{u 1:20}sum{w 1:10}   Quw(ruw-yuw)^2. How would this effect the setup? Just a guidance on setup will be appreciated.

Comment: Would the quadprog package help?

Comment: Unfortunately this typo changes the entire problem, since it's now a quadratic program instead of a linear program. Given how major that difference is, I'd suggest you just ask a new question, making sure you get the formulation right this time.

Comment: Great will do, thanks for the suggestions Josilber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Quw` and `ruw` are both data, all constraints as well as the objective are linear in the `yuw` decision variables. As a result, this is a linear programming problem that can be approached by the `lpSolve` package.

To abstract this out a bit, let's assume `R=20` and `C=10` describe the dimensions of the input matrices. Then there are `R*C` decision variables and we can assign them order `y11, y21, ... yR1, y12, y22, ... yR2, ..., y1C, y2C, ..., yRC`, reading down the columns of the matrix of variables.

The coefficient of each `yuw` variable in the objective is `-Quw`; note that the `Quw*ruw` terms in the summation are constants (aka not affected by the values we select for the decision variables) and therefore not inputted to the linear programming solver. Interestingly, this means that `ruw` actually has no effect on the optimization model solution.

The first `R*(C-1)` constraints correspond to the `yuw >= yu,w+1` constraints, and the next `(R-1)*C` constraints correspond to the `yuw >= yu-1,w` constraints. The final two constraints correspond to the `y20,1 >= 100` and `y1,10 >= 0` constraints.

We can input this model into the `lpsolve` package with the following R command, taking as input a simple Q matrix where each entry is -1 (the resulting solution should have all decision variables set to 0 except the bottom left corner, which should be 100):

```
# Sample data
Quw <- matrix(-1, nrow=20, ncol=10)
R <- nrow(Quw)
C <- ncol(Quw)

# Build constraint matrix
part1 <- matrix(0, nrow=R*(C-1), ncol=R*C)
part1[cbind(1:(R*C-R), 1:(R*C-R))] <- 1
part1[cbind(1:(R*C-R), (R+1):(R*C))] <- -1
part2 <- matrix(0, nrow=(R-1)*C, ncol=R*C)
pos2 <- as.vector(sapply(2:R, function(r) r+seq(0, R*(C-1), by=R)))
part2[cbind(1:nrow(part2), pos2)] <- 1
part2[cbind(1:nrow(part2), pos2-1)] <- -1
part3 <- rep(0, R*C)
part3[R] <- 1
part4 <- rep(0, R*C)
part4[(C-1)*R + 1] <- 1
const.mat <- rbind(part1, part2, part3, part4)

library(lpSolve)
mod <- lp(direction = "min",
          objective.in = as.vector(-Quw),
          const.mat = const.mat,
          const.dir = rep(">=", nrow(const.mat)),
          const.rhs = c(rep(0, nrow(const.mat)-2), 100, 0))
```

We can now access the model solution:

```
mod
# Success: the objective function is 100
matrix(mod$solution, nrow=R)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#  [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [11,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [12,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [13,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [14,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [15,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [16,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [17,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [18,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [19,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [20,]  100    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Note that your model could easily become infeasible if `Quw` changed (for instance if we filled it with 1 instead of -1). In these cases the model will exit with status 3 (you can see this by running `mod` or `mod$status`).