# R: Quadratic programming/ Isotonic regression

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, minimization, quadratic-programming

I want to minimise the following equation:

```
F=SUM{u 1:20}sum{w 1:10}   Quw(ruw-yuw)^2
```

with the following constraints:

```
yuw >= yu,w+1
yuw >= yu-1,w
y20,0 = 100
y0,10 = 0
yu,10 = 0
```

I have a 20*10 ruw and 20*10 quw matrix, I now need to generate a yuw matrix which adheres to the constraints. I am coding in R and am familiar with the lpsolve, optimx and quadprog packages, but don't know how to use them for this particular question. I know that I must use the quadprog package as this is a quadratic programming question. I'm not looking for a complete answer, I am wanting some guidance as to how to structure the constraint matrix and the best way to tackle the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the similarities of the optimization problem here to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948921/r-isotonic-regression-minimisation), I will borrow some language directly from my answer to that question. However they are quite a bit different (the previous problem was a linear programming problem and this is a quadratic programming problem, and the constraints differ), so they are not duplicates.

Expanding out the optimization objective we get `Quw*ruw^2 - 2*Quw*ruw*yuw + Quw*yuw^2`. We see that this is a quadratic function of the decision variables `yuw`, and thus the `solve.QP` method of the `quadProg` package can be used to solve the optimization problem.

To abstract this out a bit, let's assume `R=20` and `C=10` describe the dimensions of the input matrices. Then there are `R*C` decision variables and we can assign them order `y11, y21, ... yR1, y12, y22, ... yR2, ..., y1C, y2C, ..., yRC`, reading down the columns of the matrix of variables.

From `?solve.QP`, we read that the objective takes the form `-d'b + 0.5b'Db` for decision variables `b`. The element of `d` corresponding to decision variable `yuw` has value `2*Quw*ruw` and `D` is a diagonal matrix with the element corresponding to decision variable `yuw` taking value `2*Quw`. Note that the `solve.QP` function requires the `D` matrix to be positive definite, so we require `Quw > 0` for every `u, w` pair.

The first `R*(C-1)` constraints correspond to the `yuw >= yu,w+1` constraints, and the next `(R-1)*C` constraints correspond to the `yuw >= yu-1,w` constraints. The next `2*R` constraints correspond to the `yuC = 0` constraints (which are inputted as `yuC >= 0` and `-yuC >= 0`), and the last constraint is `-yR1 >= -100` (which is logically equivalent to `yR0 = 100`).

We can input this model into the `quadProg` package with the following R commands, using random input data:

```
# Sample data
set.seed(144)
Quw <- matrix(runif(200), nrow=20)
ruw <- matrix(runif(200), nrow=20)
R <- nrow(Quw)
C <- ncol(Quw)

# Build constraint matrix
part1 <- matrix(0, nrow=R*(C-1), ncol=R*C)
part1[cbind(1:(R*C-R), 1:(R*C-R))] <- 1
part1[cbind(1:(R*C-R), (R+1):(R*C))] <- -1
part2 <- matrix(0, nrow=(R-1)*C, ncol=R*C)
pos2 <- as.vector(sapply(2:R, function(r) r+seq(0, R*(C-1), by=R)))
part2[cbind(1:nrow(part2), pos2)] <- 1
part2[cbind(1:nrow(part2), pos2-1)] <- -1
part3 <- matrix(0, nrow=2*R, ncol=R*C)
part3[cbind(1:R, (R*C-R+1):(R*C))] <- 1
part3[cbind((R+1):(2*R), (R*C-R+1):(R*C))] <- -1
part4 <- rep(0, R*C)
part4[R] <- -1
const.mat <- rbind(part1, part2, part3, part4)

library(quadProg)
mod <- solve.QP(Dmat = 2*diag(as.vector(Quw)),
                dvec = 2*as.vector(ruw)*as.vector(Quw),
                Amat = t(const.mat),
                bvec = c(rep(0, nrow(const.mat)-1), -100))
```

We can now access the model solution:

```
# Objective (including the constant term):
mod$value + sum(Quw*ruw^2)
# [1] 9.14478
matrix(mod$solution, nrow=R)
#            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]        [,10]
#  [1,] 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.3215992 0.1818095 0.1818095 0.1818095 0.000000e+00
#  [2,] 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.2882339 0.2882339 0.000000e+00
#  [3,] 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.2882339 0.2882339 2.775558e-17
#  [4,] 0.5728478 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.2882339 0.2882339 0.000000e+00
#  [5,] 0.5728478 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.4699046 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.2882339 0.2882339 0.000000e+00
#  [6,] 0.5728478 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.4699046 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.2882339 0.2882339 0.000000e+00
#  [7,] 0.5728478 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.4699046 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.2882339 0.2882339 0.000000e+00
#  [8,] 0.5728478 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.2882339 0.2882339 0.000000e+00
#  [9,] 0.5728478 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.2882339 1.110223e-16
# [10,] 0.5728478 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.000000e+00
# [11,] 0.6298100 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.4518205 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.000000e+00
# [12,] 0.6298100 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.4518205 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.000000e+00
# [13,] 0.6298100 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.4518205 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.000000e+00
# [14,] 0.6298100 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.4518205 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.000000e+00
# [15,] 0.6298100 0.6009718 0.5111456 0.5111456 0.4518205 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.000000e+00
# [16,] 0.6298100 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.4518205 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.000000e+00
# [17,] 0.6298100 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.000000e+00
# [18,] 0.6298100 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.000000e+00
# [19,] 0.6298100 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.4346995 0.000000e+00
# [20,] 0.6298100 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.6009718 0.5643033 0.5643033 0.5643033 0.000000e+00
```

Comment: Hi Josilber, some yuw values are the same as you go along the rows and also the same as you go down the column. Does this adhere to the yuw >=yu,w+1 and yu,w >=yu-1,w constraints?

Comment: Also, the first value (20,1) should be 100 and the y0,10 = 0
yu,10 = 0 constraints don't hold, may I ask why?

Comment: @Ankit element (1, 1) is on the top left, so `yu,w >= yu,w+1`  means the numbers are non-decreasing as you move right to left, and `yu,w >= yu-1,w` means numbers are non-decreasing as you move top to bottom. I do not display `y20,0` because it does not appear in the objective value. From `y20,0 = 100` and `yu,w >= yu,w+1` I conclude that `y20,1 <= 100`, which is the constraint I added. As you can see, the final selected value for `y20,1` was 0.6298100.